# How to get the next day based on current day using NSCalendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nscalendar

I'm doing some weather app, in that i want to show the forecast for 4days i.e., current day to next 3days. I'm getting current day and the code is

NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

```
NSDateComponents* comp = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

 // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.

 NSInteger day0 = comp.weekday;

    NSLog(@"My DAY is %i", day0);


NSString *str;

NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString string];

str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",day0]; //%d or %i both is ok.

[myString appendString:str];

NSLog(@"My DAY is %@", myString);
```

And the output is 6 ie., Friday .... thats cool

How can i get the next day without incrementing the current day... I tried to increment the current day, but the problem is, if i get the current day as 7, it is incrementing to 8 no such thing in weedays right.. I'm newbie to xcode.. Help me out guys....

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [NSDateComponents new];
dayComponent.day = 1;
today = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:today options:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

> "How can i get the next day without incrementing the current day..."

If you want a NSDate object representing each day, you can use NSDateComponents to add up:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *offset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
offset.day = 1; // create a one day offset
NSDate *tomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:today options:0];
```

Then get your weekday:

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:tomorrow];
```

> "I tried to increment the current day, but the problem is, if i get the current day as 7, it is incrementing to 8 no such thing in weedays right.."

If it is enough to just increase the weekday of today, use a simple modulo (that's just basic in any programming language):

```
int weekdayOfTomorrow = (++weekdayOfToday % 7) + 1;
```